# rails where to include @media css tags?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Right now I have in my layout.html.erb some css rules with @media

```
<style>
 @media (max-width: 900px) {
    .green-button{
      display: none!important;
    }
    .chat_button{
      margin-top: 20px!important;
    }
    #myCarousel{
      height:800px!important;
    }
</style>
```

I want to get rid of them and put them in css file. In my css folder I created file  `mobile.css` and put this code there. But it doesn't work.
How do I fix this?

Comment: try put your code in `application.css` does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails is important to keep your css in order.

You should have one main `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` file where you can list all the css files to import in your application.

So, if you have a `app/assets/stylesheets/mobile.css` file, the content of `application.css` will be:

```
/*
*= require mobile
*/
```

then, in your page, you have to include within `<head>` tags the following:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
```

Please study the following to understand better Rails Assets Pipeline:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

A couple of suggestions:

- you are mixing camelCase and dashes in your css: avoid that.
- you are assigning styles to an id: avoid that.
- you are using `!important` too often: avoid that.

Only use classes to define css and don't use camelCase but only `-` (dashes). Avoid `!important` if you can. Look into a css style guide if you have time.

As a further step I would also suggest you to move to scss.
Rename your `mobile.css` into `mobile.scss` and refactor it like that:

```
$breakpoint: 900px;
@media (max-width: $breakpoint) {

  .green-button {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .chat_button{
    margin-top: 20px !important;
  }

  #myCarousel {
    height:800px !important;
  }
```

Comment: It seems to work when I add  *= require mobile at the end of my `application.css` folder. And thanks for suggestions for imporovements

Answer (score 1):

Put them into `application.css`:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .green-button { display: none; }
  .chat_button  { margin-top: 20px; }
  #myCarousel   { height:800px; }
}
```

---

> I created file `mobile.css`

You really *don't* need a separate "mobile" stylesheet if you're using `@media` queries.

`@media` queries change the *styling* of your HTML based on the viewport size. Whilst mobiles/tablets can change the viewport size, they generally don't require a completely separate CSS structure.

The old need for a "mobile" stylesheet was born from the fact that pre-iPhone mobile Internet was basic at best. Now we have full HTML rendering on phones, you just need to change how big/visible each element is.

Rails - by default - implores you to use `application.css` in your `layout`, which should include the `@media` queries:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.css
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application %>
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted, I challenge you to refute what I wrote. It's all correct.

Comment: Using application.css to define styles is the first step to badly organize your css files. The application.css should be used only to define the list of files to include.

Comment: Certainly. I understood the question to ask about adding an extra stylesheet, to which I recommended including the code in `application.css`. Still nothing stopping you putting styling into `application.css`, especially if the app is small.

Comment: thnaks too, I checked both answers, if I include css in apllication css it works fine!

Comment: Thanks! Corrasse has the right answer, but for someone (who maybe is new), mine should provide appropriate context.